# Show data from textboxes into listview in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# project have :

The XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="Revision.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Patient Information" Height="456.36" Width="935.208">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SliderStyle">
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="RangeBase.Minimum" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="RangeBase.Maximum" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="Slider.IsSnapToTickEnabled" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="RangeBase.Value" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Slider.AutoToolTipPlacement" Value="TopLeft"/>


    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Label Content="First Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,23,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Last Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,82,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Address" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,144,0,0" Name="label3" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="Security Type" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,203,0,0" Name="label4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,23,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" />
    <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,82,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" />
    <TextBox Height="36" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,136,0,0" Name="textBox3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="197" />
    <ComboBox Height="36" Margin="105,195,625,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Private Assurance" Name="PrA"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Public Assurance" Name="PA"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="No Assurance" Name="NA"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Submit" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="147,365,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click"/>
    <Button Content="Display" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="227,365,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
    <Label Content="Gender" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="maleRadio" Content="Male" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="105,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="femaleRadio" Content="Female" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Slider x:Name="redSlider" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Value="{Binding Text, ElementName=textBox5}" Margin="74,313,636,56" SmallChange="1" Height="56" Width="Auto" />
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox5"  Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=redSlider}" Margin="296,313,588,86" SelectionOpacity="1" FontSize="13" />
    <Label Content="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,313,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ListView x:Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="375" Margin="344,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="567">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="80"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address" Width="100"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Security Type" Width="80"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Gender" Width="100"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="100"
DisplayMemberBinding="" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and I have a class patient:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Revision
{
class Patient
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string securityType {get; set;}
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }

    public Patient(string fn, string ln, string ad, string st,string ge,string ag)
    {

        firstname = fn;
        lastname = ln;
        Address = ad;
        securityType = st;
        gender = ge;
        age = ag;

    }
    public override string ToString()
    {

        return string.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10} {2,-10} {3,-10} {4,-10} {5,-10}",

            firstname, lastname, Address, securityType, gender,age);
    }
}
}
```

and the main program

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   // Patient [] patients = new Patient{}
    Patient [] patients = new Patient[100];
    private List<Patient> books = new List<Patient>();
    int i=0;
    string g;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "";
        if (PrA.IsSelected)
        {
            x = PrA.Content.ToString();
        }

        else if (PA.IsSelected)
        {
            x = PA.Content.ToString();
        }
        else if (NA.IsSelected)
        {
            x = NA.Content.ToString();
        }

        if (maleRadio.IsChecked == true)
            g = "Male";
        if(femaleRadio.IsChecked==true)
            g="Female";

       patients[i] = new Patient(
             textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, g, textBox5.Text, x);
        i = i + 1;
       // Patient[] patients = { 
         //                        new Patient (
           //   textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, x)};

        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();

        textBox5.Clear();


    }
}
```

So the question I want to display the data entered in the textboxes,radio button and combo box... in the List view

Comment: `public Patient(string fn, string ln, string ad, string st,string ge,string ag)` - OMG dude, please don't create constructors like that. Use Object Initializer Syntax instead, or otherwise give proper name to constructor parameters.

Comment: you dont reply to my question

Comment: No, because your code is a disaster. You must learn MVVM instead of manually reading stuff from textboxes. Use databinding.

Comment: Nope - he didn't reply, but gave a good advice for free..

Comment: can any one solve my problem?

Comment: @husseinHajjali your problem is that you NEED to learn MVVM BEFORE trying to do stuff in WPF. Nobody can solve that, except yourself, by learning the pattern. Also, please don't use the Visual Studio designer to create the UI. Learn to write XAML.

Comment: I learned WPF a couple of years before I ever heard about MVVM. MVVM is smart, but not a must. You should understand how databinding works though. And the layout model used by WPF. And MVVM. But learning all this _before_ you try to do stuff...? I would go for _while_ you try instead... If you wait until you have learned everything, it could take a while before you get started...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of getting your data into the listview would be through databinding. Databinding is the way that WPF uses to transport data between your view and your code.

All wpf controls that can show multiple items, like listview, listbox, combobox etc, has a `ItemSource` property. By setting this property to an enumerable, the view will display each item in the collection.

By default, it will just render each item as a textblock showing the result of calling ToString() on each object. There are several ways of customizing this. In your case, you have defined columns with a `GridView` and `GridViewColumn`s. Each `GridViewColumn` has a `DisplayMemberBinding` which can be binded to the property you want to display in that column.

So...

I'm not sure how easy it will be for you to use this. As mentioned by others, you really should learn a little bit about binding in wpf, and the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern. MVVM really helps keeping the code clean.

Anyways...

Your view could be changed to something like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="375" Margin="344,23,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="567" ItemsSource="{Binding patients}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=firstname}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=lastname}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Address" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=Address}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Security Type" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=securityType}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Gender" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=gender}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path=age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I would change your fixed size array of patients to a `ObservableCollection<Patient>`. A collection that can grow in size is almost always better than a fixed size one. The `ObservableCollection<>` has some extra tricks as well. It will notify the view whenever items are added or removed.

Take a look at [wpftutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net). You will find a nice [introduction to binding](http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html) , [MVVM](http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html) and a lot more.